# How to create exe file for Two class libraries in Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, class-library

I have to create virtual camera of my winform app to access it in skype. I have done it by referring this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437617/DirectShow-Virtual-Video-Capture-Source-Filter-in). But I can only rebuild the app. Because it contains only Class Libraries. So when rebuild the app, bin folder contains it's dll files only. How can I create exe file for the same to send it to my clients?
It is installing a .bat file for COM registration.

I want to achieve this all in one exe file. I have tried by adding a new project as winform application inside this and added this two libraries as reference of winform application. But that install.bat file is not executing

Pleas see attached screen shots of solution explorer, rebuild, and bin folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Class libraries are not executable you will have to create a windows application project and add these libraries to the project references and rebuild the windows appli project. You would find exe file on the bin folder of Windows application project